# .replaceAll not supported in Snowflake JavaScript UDF?

Tags: javascript, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to understand why the code below works as a JavaScript UDF in Snowflake:

```
create or replace function clean_name_function_test(COL string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$  
  return COL.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '-');
$$;


set test_string = 'Brand - Test';
select clean_name_function_test($test_string);
```

returning `brand-- test` and why the code below *(where `.replace` is swapped for `.replaceAll`)* does not:

```
create or replace function clean_name_function_test(COL string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$  
  return COL.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-');
$$;


set test_string = 'Brand - Test';
select clean_name_function_test($test_string);
```

throwing the error `JavaScript execution error: Uncaught TypeError: COL.toLowerCase(...).replaceAll is not a function in CLEAN_NAME_FUNCTION_TEST at ' return COL.toLowerCase().replaceAll(' ', '-');' position 27 stackstrace: CLEAN_NAME_FUNCTION_TEST line: 2`.

Comment: Sounds like they haven't integrated the new proposal yet. Use a global regex instead

Comment: Not sure why my question was marked as a duplicate since
[How to replace all occurrences of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string) does not answer why `replaceAll` isn't supported in Snowflake Javascript UDFs.

Comment: To complement what CertainPerformance said: `replaceAll` is a kind of new addition to JavaScript, and Snowflake's JavaScript implementation still hasn't added this (but soon it will)